# Google Ads suddenly went blank after sometime in real device

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, reverse-engineering

I am working on Ads injection in apk file. i do reverse engineering in apk file to add ads.

I follow below steps:

1. Extract .apk file using apktool and get all files/folder from apk(like res, smali folder, AndroidManifest.xml file)
2. Inject ads when app gets start (by copy smali file, modify .xml file)
3. Rebuild apk file after ads injection

Then i run this apk file using android emulator, in that ads is injected
after that i installed same apk file in my physical android device, it is showing ads at start of app for some time ( 10-15 repetitive execution) and after sometime it is showing me blank screen and blank screen disappeared automatically.

If anyone knows that why ads showing properly in android emulator but not in real device, please help.

Thanks.

Comment: which type of error code get in fail ad

Comment: @KishanViramgama how can i get error code?

Comment: check this link https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner `onAdFailedToLoad` mehod get error code